Details in the proof of the existence of normal coordinate chart
I am reading complex differential geometry by Fangyang Zheng. I have a problem when reading the proof of the following lemma:

Lemma. For any $p$ in a Riemannian manifold $M^{n}$, there exists a local coordinate system $\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)$ in a neighborhood of $p$ such that $\left.g_{i j}\right|_{p}=\delta_{i j}$ and $\left.d g_{i j}\right|_{p}=0$, where $g_{i j}=\left\langle\partial_{i}, \partial_{j}\right\rangle$.
Proof. First let us take a local coordinate system $x$ such that $p$ is the origin, and $g_{i j}(0)=\delta_{i j}$. Write $\frac{\partial g_{i j}}{\partial x_{k}}(0)$ as $A_{i j k}$. It is symmetric with respect to the first two positions. Define $n \times n$ symmetric matrices $B^{(1)}, \ldots, B^{(n)}$ by
$$B_{i j}^{(k)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(A_{k i j}+A_{k j i}-A_{i j k}\right)$$
Then $B_{j k}^{(i)}+B_{i k}^{(j)}=A_{i j k}$. So if we define a new coordinate system by
$$\tilde{x}_{i}=x_{i}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j, k=1}^{n} B_{j k}^{(i)} x_{j} x_{k},$$
then it is easy to see that under $\tilde{x}$, $\tilde{g}_{i j}(0)=\delta_{i j}$ and $d \tilde{g}_{i j}(0)=0$.

I don't know why it is easy to see that $\tilde{g}_{i j}(0)=\delta_{i j}$ and $d \tilde{g}_{i j}(0)=0$. My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{g}_{i j}&=\langle\tilde\partial_i,\tilde\partial_j\rangle\\
&=\sum_{k,l}\left\langle\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial\tilde x_i}\partial_k.\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial\tilde x_j}\partial_l\right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{k,l}g_{kl}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial\tilde x_i}\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial\tilde x_j}.
\end{align*}
So we need to compute $\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial\tilde x_j}$, but it seems impossible since taking partial derivate of $\displaystyle\tilde{x}_{i}=x_{i}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j, k=1}^{n} B_{j k}^{(i)} x_{j} x_{k}$ with respect to $\tilde x_l$, we get
$$\delta_{il}=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial\tilde x_l}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j, k=1}^{n} B_{j k}^{(i)}\left(\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial\tilde x_l}x_k+x_j\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial\tilde x_l}\right),\quad i,l=1,\cdots,n.$$
How can we solve $\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial\tilde x_j}$ from the above equation system? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is another presentation of the same calculation: https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/01/28/RiemannCurvature.html

For brevity, we use Einstein's summation convention, which means we need to write the coordinates $x_i$ as $x^i$. Differentiating the coordinate transformation equation, we have
$$d\tilde{x}^{i}=dx^{i}+\frac{1}{2} B_{k l}^{(i)} x^{l}dx^{k} +\frac{1}{2} B_{lk}^{(i)}x^{l} dx^{k}=dx^{i}+ B_{k l}^{(i)} x^{l}dx^{k}.$$
So
\begin{align*}
g&=\tilde g_{ij}d\tilde x^i\otimes d\tilde x^j\\
&=\tilde g_{ij}(dx^{i}+B_{k l}^{(i)} x^{l}dx^{k})\otimes(dx^{j}+B_{\alpha\beta}^{(j)} x^{\beta}dx^{\alpha})\\
&=\tilde g_{ij}dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}+\tilde g_{ij}B_{\alpha\beta}^{(j)}x^{\beta}dx^{i}\otimes  dx^{\alpha}+\tilde g_{ij}B_{k l}^{(i)} x^{l}dx^{k}\otimes dx^{j}+\tilde g_{ij}B_{k l}^{(i)} x^{l}B_{\alpha\beta}^{(j)} x^{\beta}dx^{k}\otimes dx^{\alpha}\\
&=\tilde g_{ij}dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}+\tilde g_{i\alpha}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)}x^{\beta}dx^{i}\otimes  dx^{j}+\tilde g_{kj}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}+\tilde g_{k\alpha}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)} x^{\beta}dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}\\
&=\left(\tilde g_{ij}+\tilde g_{i\alpha}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)}x^{\beta}+\tilde g_{kj}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}+\tilde g_{k\alpha}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)} x^{\beta}\right)dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$g_{ij}=\tilde g_{ij}+\tilde g_{i\alpha}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)}x^{\beta}+\tilde g_{kj}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}+\tilde g_{k\alpha}B_{i l}^{(k)} x^{l}B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)} x^{\beta},$$
and thus $\tilde g_{ij}(0)=g_{ij}(0)=\delta_{ij}$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
A_{ij\gamma}=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)&=\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)+\tilde g_{i\alpha}(0)B_{j\beta}^{(\alpha)}\delta_\gamma^\beta+\tilde g_{kj}(0)B_{i l}^{(k)}\delta_\gamma^l\\
&=\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)+\delta_{i\alpha}B_{j\gamma}^{(\alpha)}+\delta_{kj}B_{i\gamma}^{(k)}\\
&=\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)+B_{j\gamma}^{(i)}+B_{i\gamma}^{(j)}\\
&=\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)+A_{ij\gamma}.
\end{align*}
Therefore $\dfrac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x^\gamma}(0)=0$.

EDITED:
Let $\tilde x=f(x)$ and note that $Df(0)=I$ (since the derivative of the quadratic terms vanishes at the origin). Note that $\tilde g_{ij}=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x_j}\rangle = \langle\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial\bar x_i},\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial\bar x_j}\rangle$, so $\tilde G(0) = D(f^{-1})(0)^\top G(0) D(f^{-1})(0) = I$.
Write $Df_k(x)=v_k(x)=[v_{jk}]$. By definition, $D^2f_k = B^{(k)}$, so $\frac{\partial v_{jk}}{\partial x_m}=B^{(k)}_{mj}$. Since $ G(x)=Df(x)^\top \tilde G(x) Df(x)$, we have $ g_{ij} = \sum v_{ki}\tilde g_{k\ell}v_{\ell j}$, and so
\begin{align*}
A_{ijm}=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_m}(0) &= \sum \frac{\partial v_{ki}}{\partial x_m}(0)\delta_{k\ell}\delta_{\ell j} + \delta_{ik}\frac{\partial\tilde g_{k\ell}}{\partial x_m}(0)\delta_{\ell j} + \delta_{ik}\delta_{k\ell}\frac{\partial v_{\ell j}}{\partial x_m}(0)\\
&=\sum B^{(i)}_{mk}\delta_{k\ell}\delta_{\ell j}+\delta_{ik}\frac{\partial\tilde g_{k\ell}}{\partial x_m}(0)\delta_{\ell j}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{k\ell}B^{(j)}_{m\ell} \\
&=B^{(i)}_{mj}+\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial x_m}+B^{(j)}_{mi}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial\tilde g_{ij}}{\partial m} = A_{ijm}-B^{(i)}_{mj}-B^{j}_{mi} = 0,$$
as desired.

I came up with a proof recently while reading the proof that $d\omega=0$ is equivalent to the existence of normal coordinates on Kahler manifold and have posted it, but I didn't find the missing minus sign. The author's proof seems to me correct.

Yes, you made me go back and think about my argument. My formula for $\tilde g$ — which I wrote down based on standard parametric formulas without thinking — is incorrect. Indeed, your argument is easier and should have been what I did. I was thinking sloppily about the formula $$\tilde g_{ij} = \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^j}\rangle = \sum g_{k\ell} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial\bar x^i} \frac{\partial x^\ell}{\partial\bar x^j}.$$  So there's actually the derivative of $f^{-1}$ here, not of $f$. Bad me!

I've edited to give the correct computation. I actually prefer yours.
